# ajax: not getting value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i'm not getting company_name value to show_house_members.php.
but event_name can get over there. is there any error in this ajax code? i'm just a beginner in this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_mem").click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="loader1"><img src="imgdropdown/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');

    var datastring = "&company_name="+$('#company_name').val()+"&event_name="+$('#event_name').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'show_house_members.php',
        data: datastring,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.loader1').hide();
            $("#house_members").after(data);
        }
    });
});
        });
```

and here is my form

```
<p><label>company name</label>
                <select name="company_name" id="company_name">




                <?php
                include("config/dbconfig.php");
                                     $res=mysql_query("select *from tbl_company");
                                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=".$row[0].">".$row[1]."</option>";
                                    }

                ?>
                </select></p>


                <!--event names dynamically added here by using jquery ajax -->             
                <p><label>Event name</label>
                <select name="event_name" id="event_name">
                </select></p> 

                <a href="#"  id="add_mem"  name="add_mem" style="padding-left: 280px;" "><img title='add_house_members'  src='images/button.png'/></a><form action="add_house_entry.php" method="GET|POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="f3" class="smart-green" style="width: 450px;   height:290px;padding-top: 50px;padding-left: 20px;" >
                <h1>Enter House details  </h1>
```

Comment: Have you debug using `console.log(datastring);` ?

Comment: also, in chrome dev tools, hit the network tab to see the ajax call and the result received. i also recommend not using mysql_* functions as they are obsolete in newer versions of php, read up on using mysqli_* functions instead :)

Comment: @Rikesh console.log says  event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `&` before `company_name` in your `datastring` value:

```
var datastring = "&company_name="+$('#company_name').val()+"&event_name="+$('#event_name').val();
// -------------  ^ remove this
```

Comment: even now its not getting :( . any other thingshould i do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use serialize() method to get the datastring like below

```
 var datastring = $('#form').serialize();
```

it will generate datastring automatically!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
data : { datastring : datastring },
```

Instead of

```
data : datastring,
```

Please refer to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/